# Is $(f(x) + g(x))/2$ equal to $(f(y) + g(y))/2$?

Tags: functions, average

If I have two functions $y = f(x)$ and $y = g(x)$, and I define the mean function as $y = (f(x) + g(x))/2$.

Is this equivalent to rearranging for $x$ and determining $x = (f(y) + g(y))/2$?

Visually, if I want to average two functions graphically (say supply and demand functions) - does my answer change depending on which axis I choose to define the dependent and independent variable?

Comment: What about b=(f(a)+g(a))/2?  Will the solution change?

Comment: Graphically, what do you think the average will depend on? Think about it for some time.

Comment: Averaging doesn't depend on which letters (x or y) you use.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 thanks for this, conceptually I understand what is happening now. Averaging as y = f(x) results in an average function which is the midpoint on the y-axis (vertically). 
Averaging as x = f(y) results in an average function which is the midpoint on the x-axis (horizontally).
This can easily be seen by graphing the average functions in the example provided by user as functions of x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In other words, we need to determine whether or not the mean of the two functions coincides with the mean of the inverse functions.

Well, assuming the inverse functions exist, this property is not true in general.

Indeed, let consider for example the linear functions:

- $y=x$
- $y=2x$

then we have:

- mean function $y=\frac 3 2 x$
- mean of the inverse functions $ x=\frac 3 4 y$